# How to make the description text line up beside the image, below the h1

Tags: html, css, display

I'm trying to make the description text at the bottom line up beside the image. I've tried floats, changing the display property to inline, all to no avail.

**IMPORTANT: It looks right in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sec55/7aj3c4ce/), but NOT on the [web](http://www.ccsda.church)**. What could be the problem?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="event-wrapper">
   <div class="event">
   <p class="event-date">SEP 15</p>
   <img class="event-image" src="images/backgrounds/graphicstock/AS6_3297_2-103.jpg">
   <h1>Day at Winnekeag</h1>
   <p class="event-text">This is some text about this event. It will be at Camp Winnekeag. We hope you can join us. </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.event-wrapper {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 2rem 15%;
}
.event {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
.event-date {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding:.5rem;
}
.event-image {
  display:inline;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.event-wrapper h1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
}
.event-text {
    float: left;
    margin-top:.5rem;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Please note that the website is in the early alpha stage of development.

Comment: remove float from `event-text`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Confirmed, that works!

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Float try `position: relative;` and use margin for placing it on the required place where you want